# What is the typical error of a voltage follower opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I am trying to identify design elements that might have error from unit to unit.  In the design I am looking at, there is a voltage follower configuration for an opamp (in this case, an LM2014), which has an ideal gain of 1 (by definition).  Of course, in the real world nothing is ideal, everything has some amount of variability and error, and I would speculate that the gain of a unity gain opamp is no exception.

I was unable to find any rule of thumb on real world gain errors for this configuration, and I'm not good enough with discrete electronics and opamp specs to narrow the answer down for myself.

What should be considered a typical error in the gain of a unity gain opamp?  (e.g., is it safe to say 3, 4, or 5 decimal places?)  How should I go about figuring this out from the specs of a given opamp so I can do this myself next time?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhn6JF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Check opamp part number?  The biggest error will likely be the input offset voltage.  Typically 1mV or so.. but can be a lot smaller.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion about naming on the 'net, but I'd call that a "voltage follower", not a "current follower".

Comment: Excellent point, I edited to reflect your comment The Photon.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, this one has an input offset of .12uV, so that's basically my error?

Comment: @b if input offset voltage is the main concern, look for "chopper stabilised" op amps. Also, beware that some op-amps are not stable at unity gain, they need to be operated at some higher gain.

Comment: Link to part?  0.12uV! is it chopper stabilized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With two voltages (input, output) I would expect that it is likely a "voltage follower".
More than that, are you sure about the part number?

When speaking about classical voltage opamps the real closed-loop gain for the unity gain amplifier (follower) is

\$Acl = \dfrac{Ao}{1+Ao}\$  with Ao: Open-loop gain.

Fort a typical value \$Ao=10^5\$ (100 dB) we have

\$Acl = \dfrac{10^5}{1+10^5}\$ which is very close to unity.

However, it is to be noted that the open-loop gain Ao continuously decreases with rising frequencies and causes - in addition - phase deviations. Hence, we have Ao=Ao(jw).

However, each opamp has an input offset error between µV (very good devices) and some mV (universal types). This voltage is amplified with unity and, thus, appears with the same value at the output. But it is not an amplification error but a fixed dc shift of the operational point.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect voltage follower instead of current follower.

The LM 2014 has an input offset of .12uV, so I will choose to consider that gain = 1.0 and move on with my analysis.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

The error is essentially the input voltage offset of the op-amp.

This can range from microvolts to millivolts. Traditionally, op-amps with \$V_{os}\$ below 1 mV have been sold as "precision" op-amps. And you'll find this as one of the main categories of op-amps on most vendors webpages (Analog, TI, Linear, ...).

If this parameter is critical, you should also look for a part whose datasheet specifies the temperature coefficient of the offset, and be sure that your circuit will remain in spec throughout its expected operating temperature range.

Comment: Unfortunately the data table that comes up when you go to "precision amplifiers" at ti.com seems to actually be all op-amps. But you will notice that the description text (the title of the datasheet) only uses the word *precision* when Vos is 1 mV or lower.

Answer (score 3):

The error will be composed of the input offset voltage and change of input offset voltage with input common mode voltage (CMRR) plus error due to finite gain- so a small offset and a small gain error.

The error due to finite gain with a precision op-amp is usually pretty low at DC, but increases with increasing frequency.

Noise will generally be higher than the number(s) shown on the datasheet since it's usually specified with a high gain, which pretty much eliminates noise from the output stage.

Comment: Excellent, did you mention output impedance? (Well, when used as source into inverting amps.)

Answer (score 2):

Many have told you to beware input offset voltages, which will be your main error.  You may also see slew rate limits, which may distort your output at fast transiotions.  Also, many op amp outputs can not reach closer than a few volts below the power rails, so you may have saturation problems.